# I'm trying to rename directories but getting two errors, how to solve this errors?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created this method:

```
private void DeletionCheck()
{
    DirectoryInfo listDirs = new DirectoryInfo(MainDirectory);
    var dirs = listDirs.EnumerateDirectories().OrderBy(d => d.Name);

    for (var directoryIndex = 1; directoryIndex <= dirs.Count(); directoryIndex++)
    {
        if (directoryIndex != dirs[directoryIndex - 1].Name)
        {
            Directory.Move(listDirs[directoryIndex - 1], directoryIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

The first error is on this line:

```
dirs[directoryIndex - 1]
```

Error:

> Error 60  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable'

The second error is on this line:

```
listDirs[directoryIndex - 1]
```

Error:

> Error 61  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo'

What I want to do in this method is to check if a sun directory in `MainDirectory` was deleted then sort all the other directories by name and rename them to re order them by name.

And since all the sub directories names are ending with a number for example:

```
Event 000001
Event 000002
```

So to parse the number of each sub directory and sort and order with the numbers part of the directories names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list or array instead of the (non-executed) LINQ-query which has no indexer:

`var dirs = listDirs.EnumerateDirectories().OrderBy(d => d.Name).ToList();`

Note that most LINQ methods are executed lazily (also called deferred executed). That means everytime you use a `foreach` or method that executes it implicitly like `ToList` or `Count`(!) the query is evaluated again.

**Update**: i guess that you also want to compare a directory-name with the previous directory-name. So change this

```
if (directoryIndex != dirs[directoryIndex - 1].Name)
```

to

```
if (dirs[directoryIndex].Name != dirs[directoryIndex - 1].Name)
```

You cannot and you don't want to compare an `int` with the directory-name.

The same applies to `Directory.Move` which needs the target directory and not an index. So change

```
 Directory.Move(listDirs[directoryIndex - 1], directoryIndex);
```

to (also using `Directory.Info.FullName`)

```
 Directory.Move(listDirs[directoryIndex - 1].FullName, listDirs[directoryIndex].FullName);
```

Comment: I did but then on this part: directoryIndex != dirs[directoryIndex - 1].Name i'm getting error you can't use != for int and string. And on the second part the second erorr i changed it to dirs: Directory.Move(dirs[directoryIndex - 1], directoryIndex); and i'm getting error since Directory.Move should get string,string

Comment: @yairshalvi: i assume that you are confusing the index with the directory-name at that index. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Tim error on both: listDirs[directoryIndex - 1], listDirs[directoryIndex] same erorr: Error 60 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo'

Comment: @yairshalvi. i have overlooked that you are using `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories`. Use `FullName` instead.